# Specifying IPv4 on Android as preferred for a given connection

Tags: android, networking, dns, ipv4

I have a backend which is only reachable via IPv4.

How can I tell my app that a specific OkHttp or WebSocket connection should inform the lookup component that it should not query `AAAA` first, but ask directly for the `A` record?

Comment: If the destination is IPv4-only, then it should not have a `AAAA` record, only an `A` record, so there should not be a problem.

Comment: @RonMaupin The query for `AAAA` yields an empty response, as it should be. I'm asking this to see if it's possible to prevent that `AAAA` query being issued in the first place. Or is it possible to insert the IPv4 address in the `AAAA` response, so that no second lookup is needed?

Comment: It should be asking for both, and the only response would be the `A` record. The way it works has been thoroughly tested, and it is designed to use the first response. That way, if the destination adds or changes to IPv6, then you would use IPv6 as the preferred communication if it answers first. The way it works is designed to help you move towards IPv6 if it is there.

Comment: Sure, but I know that IPv6 is not there, and could disable the code snippet once I add IPv6. At least on Android, the IPv4 query is only issued after the response for the IPv6 query has been received.

Comment: That seems to be akin to knowing the MAC address of a destination on the LAN, and deciding to make a permanent ARP table entry so that you do not need to use ARP requests to get the MAC address. It sounds too anal. You should simply let the network stack do its job, and not worry about things like this. It really gains you nothing. It is not like it waits for an IPv6 response first; it asks for both, and uses the first response.

Comment: "It is not like it waits for an IPv6 response first" unfortunately it appears to be that way, since I was initially dropping `AAAA`-queries on the DNS server, which extended the connection process to around 30 seconds, until the `A` record was fetched. But I'm not the expert here, if you advise me against this kind of optimization, I'll gladly do it.

Comment: OS bug? _[RFC 6555, Happy Eyeballs: Success with Dual-Stack Hosts](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6555)_ is the standard to be followed that prevents such things. "_When a server's IPv4 path and protocol are working, but the server's IPv6 path and protocol are not working, a dual-stack client application experiences significant connection delay compared to an IPv4-only client. This is undesirable because it causes the dual-stack client to have a worse user experience. This document specifies requirements for algorithms that reduce this user-visible delay and provides an algorithm._"

Comment: That RFC was then updated by _[RFC 8305, Happy Eyeballs Version 2: Better Connectivity Using Concurrency](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8305)_: "_Many communication protocols operating over the modern Internet use hostnames. These often resolve to multiple IP addresses, each of which may have different performance and connectivity characteristics. Since specific addresses or address families (IPv4 or IPv6) may be blocked, broken, or sub-optimal on a network, clients that attempt multiple connections in parallel have a chance of establishing a connection more quickly. This document specif..._"